# How to operate figures described by latex packages?

Tags: graphics, floats

I am trying to write a go book using the latex package igo.
here is the example given by the igo' User Manual:

[image]

I don't know how to operate the figure described by the igo statements, put it anywhere I want, for example, as in the manual, the figure are put on the right side of texts.I've tried the \begin{figure} statements, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1.25in,right=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{igo}

\begin{document}
%  text
\begin{figure}[H]
\white{b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g3,g2,c3}
\black{b3,b2,c2,d3,e3,f3,f2}
\shortstack{\showfullgoban\\White to kill}
\end{figure}
%  text
\end{document}
```

This is the result:
[image]

I need your help, thanks!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `figure` is a float environment. If you use it, you are telling TeX to move it to the 'best location'. If you want the diagram in a particular place, you do not want it to float so don't use a float environment. Note that you can always look at the source for the documentation of a package to see how something is done.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the relevant excerpt from the [user manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/igo/igo.tex):

```
Let's start with an exercise taken from a book by James Davies, \textit{Life and Death}\footnote{Elementary Go Series vol. 4, Kiseido Publishing Company, \copyright 1975, 1996}~:

\medskip
\begin{minipage}[c][1.0\height][c]{0.65\textwidth}
\begin{verbatim}
    \white{b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g3,g2,c3}
    \black{b3,b2,c2,d3,e3,f3,f2}
    \begin{center}
        \shortstack{\showgoban\\White to kill}
    \end{center}
\end{verbatim}
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[c][1.0\height][r]{0.25\textwidth}
\white{b4,c4,d4,e4,f4,g3,g2,c3}
\black{b3,b2,c2,d3,e3,f3,f2}
\begin{center}
    \shortstack{\showgoban\\White to kill}
\end{center}
\end{minipage}
```

Note that this code does not use the `figure` environment. `figure` is a float environment. If you use it, you are telling TeX to move it to the 'best location'. If you want the diagram in a particular place, you do not want it to float so don't use a float environment.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps what you are looking for is how to wrap a your text around your figure.  This can be done with the `wrapfigure` environment (inspired by the [`LaTeX Wikibook`](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions))

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{kantlipsum} %To generate lipsum

\begin{document}

\kant %Lipsum

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{demo}
  \caption{Your caption here}
\end{wrapfigure}

\kant %Lipsum

\end{document}
```

This is the result:

[image]

You could also be interested in using the `tabular` environment, or as the other answer, the `minipage`.

Comment: Yes, the minipage and wrapfigure can satisfy all my needs, thanks!